# PCollection<Entity> to PCollection<TableRows>

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to use Dataflow to query all my kinds in Datastore and write them into date-segmented partitions in BigQuery. The reading part is easy with `DatastoreIO.read()` and gives me a `PCollection<Entity>`.

BigQuery expects a `PCollection<TableRow>`, can I implicitly convert from one to the other? My data involves some unpredictable fields (eg bags data in embedded properties) so I can't convert explicitly all the fields.

Also, if it's relevant to the matter, I'd like to use a `SerializableFunction` to dynamically set the destination table for each datastore entity (which will be YYYYMMDD_kind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to transform the `PCollection<Entity>` to `PCollection<TableRow>` yourself. The API for `BigQueryIO.write()` expects a `TableRow`. To transform them you'll need to apply a `ParDo` over the top of the `PCollection<Entity>`.

As a side note, you can also load Datastore backups directly into BigQuery without using Dataflow. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-cloud-datastore).

Comment: Can the ParDo auto detect columns types?

Comment: What do you mean? You need to specify the type of `I` (input) and `O` (output) - in your case `Entity` and `TableRow` respectively.

Comment: I mean do I have to assign every property by hand? Eg row.id = entity.id

Comment: Yes, as far as I know this is the only way.